# Kid's story: freed witch causes strange weather

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I believe I got this from a BookMobile in the US, around 1973.

Set in 1950s or 1960s.  A child (from the city, or maybe from the US) is sent to live with relatives in rural England, maybe for summer vacation.  While there, the kids accidentally free a witch from imprisonment.  She causes strange weather, which may have been cold/blizzards, to affect the local area, which baffles scientists.  Eventually a druid re-imprisons the witch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembered the title while packing up my books, and hoping I actually find it.  It's *The Frightened Forest*, by Ann Turnbull.  It was published in 1974, so it must have been brand-new when I read it.

[image: cover]